# VBA Open Access in Runtime

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

How can i open Access in Runtime ? I tried it with the Code below but it seems he opens the full Version Access and not the runtime Version.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run ("""U:\Database1.accdb""")
```

Comment: `.Run ("""C:\PathToRuntim\MSACCESS.EXE"" ""U:\Database1.accdb""")` Try to specify the path to the runtime

Comment: or you could change the extension from accdb to accdr

Answer (score 0):

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run ("""U:\Database1.accdb"" /runtime")
```